# Delete row but retain expected cells in excel

Tags: excel

How can I remove row but still retain 1 cell which I don't want to remove. Something like these below pictures

I would like to delete row 3rd and all of content in this row, but still retain content in cell "K3"

First, It'will like this

[image]

and after remove row 3rd, It remove all of content in row 3rd but still retain character "C" in Cell K3

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove only cells `a3:c3`:

- **Select them** by dragging with the mouse (press and *hold* the **left** mouse button on `a3` and then drag to `c3`)
- Click with the **right** mouse button *on this selection*. The **pops-up menu** will appear.
- Choose **Remove...** from this context menu. The **dialog** will appear.
- Choose **Move cells up** from this dialog.

Comment: Where is the context menu and dialog, I tried but I can't find them, Could you please give me some images

Comment: The **context menu** pops-up if you **right-click with mouse** on your (previous) selection (`A3:C3`). Then, if you chose from this context menu "**Remove..."**, pops-up the **dialog**.

Comment: I slightly expanded my answer to it has more details. Look at it.